# bootstrap pills

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

im using bootstrap pills as my navigation bar.problem is it is not showing the curent active pill with blue color background(like bootstrap) 
here is my code

```
<div style="margin-left: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-top: 10px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="Project.php">Projects</a></li>

        <li class=""><a href="#">Employee</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

the output is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/irshadhassan/bwhme/)

only the home pill is focused

Comment: Looks fine to me. Check again your css. You're using default bootstrap.css file?

Comment: yap im using default bootstrap.css i think im missing a simple trick here

Comment: I hope that you understand pills don't have any functionality? So you can manually set `.active` class, or write your own js code to remove/add that class on clicked `li` element. P.S. Check again your output link above.

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/vpVhV/ As @MiljanPuzović said, it won;t automatically change the 'active' class itself. You have to do something to make that happen yourself.

Comment: found the solution just a simple trick   add data-toggle="pill" for every anchor tag

Comment: I gave you code in my answer, but I still don't understand what do you want. If you need something like I wroted in my answer, why are links in your anchors new php pages. If you click on those, you must manually set active class for current page. This makes sense only if you will load those .php pages via ajax.

Comment: youre jquery in the demo is only working fine with <a href="#"> elements.others not working as expected

Comment: Well, if you put inside anchor tags links to other pages, ofcourse this will not work.

Comment: yap i want to put anchor tags links to other page.what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code inside `script` tags:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".nav-pills li").click(function(){
       $(".active").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bwhme/2/)

Comment: yap i think you are correct it is(data-toggle="pill") just highlighting not going to the target href

Answer (score 0):

To give a full answer based on the comments, your JSFiddle works exactly as expected. The item with the .active class will have the blue background for the pill.

However what I believe you expect to happen is when you click on a link that the pill will automatically become active, this is not how it works.

You will need to generate the menu on the fly and assign the active class during generation or on each page use JS to assign the active class to the correct menu list item. For ease of use I would suggest assigning ID's to the list items so you can do the following:

So say you click on the second menu item, on the Projects.php page you could have the following jquery.

```
$('#project').addClass("active");
```

Assuming you gave the menu items IDs.

Comment: gave id for every menu item and in each page put the jquery as you mentioned  ex:$('#project').addClass("active");